# Haskell data structures oddity

Tags: haskell, data-structures, types

I've been attempting to write a small file to try out a bag-like data structure. So far my code is as follows:

```
data Fruit = Apple | Banana | Pear deriving (Eq, Show)
data Bag a = EmptyBag | Contents [(a, Integer)]

emptyBag :: Bag a
emptyBag = EmptyBag

unwrap :: [a] -> a
unwrap [x] = x

isObject theObject (obj, inte) = theObject == obj

count :: Bag a -> a -> Integer
count (Contents [xs]) theObject = snd (unwrap (filter (isObject theObject) [xs]))
count EmptyBag _ = 0
```

But when I try and run it I get the error 
    Could not deduce (Eq a) from the context ()
       arising from a use of 'isObject' at ....

Whereas when I take the count function out and call
    snd(unwrap(filter (isObject Banana) [(Apple,1),(Banana,2)]))
it happily returns 2.

Any clues on why this is, or advice on writing this kind of data structure would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's no need for an `EmptyBag` constructor; use `Contents []` instead.

Comment: `count` will also crash when you try to do something like `count (Contents [(Banana,2),(Apple,3)]) Apple` as `[xs]` only matches on lists with one element!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(==)` can only be used in a context that includes `Eq`, but when you declared `count` you didn't include that context.  If I'm reading correctly, that would be

```
count :: Eq a => Bag a -> a -> Integer
```

If you declare `count` without including the type, you can ask `ghci` for the inferred type; or just ask for the inferred type of `snd (unwrap (filter (isObject Banana) [(Apple,1),(Banana,2)]))`

Comment: Your solution is correct, but I don't entirely see why; I presumed since the function isObject works for comparisons, it wouldn't stop working in this context - what exactly does adding Eq a => change in the program?

Comment: `Eq a` tells your compiler that `theObject` is a member of the `Eq` typeclass - namely, that you can test if it's equal to something else of the same type.  There are certain data types (functions are the best example) that are not members of the `Eq` typeclass.  (For example, (+1) and ((+2).(-1))  cannot be tested for equality, although in almost all cases they will return the same result.)

Comment: Secretly, a typeclass function such as `(==)` is looked up in a table containing the information about the type; the `Eq a =>` declares the type of this table, which is passed as an additional argument behind the scenes.  (If you look at the GHC Core output you will see the actual tables being passed around.)  With `isObject` you let GHC work out the type itself, and it did so, including the `Eq a` constraint; but when you specify the type of `count` yourself, you don't get to leave things like that out (not without some fairly hairy Oleg-isms, at least). It's all or nothing.

Comment: Removing the explicit type signature on `count` also fixes the problem. Then you could use ghci to see what type is inferred.